# Rest Composite Resource

Tags: api, integration, rest

I try to insert a parent record with own child records using an external id (`Serial__c` field), but I receive this error:

> "statusCode": "INVALID_FIELD", "message": "Cannot reference a foreign
>   key field Account."

Why??

This is the request:

```js
{
"records" :[{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "Order", "referenceId" : "ref1"},
    "Status": "Draft",
    "Description": "test rest api",
    "DocumentNumber__c": "269",
    "AlfaDocument__c": "CO",
    "AgentCode__c": null,
    "SupplierCode__c": null,
    "DocumentTotal__c": null,
    "DocumentDate__c": null,
    "EffectiveDate" : "2019-02-05",
    "Account" :
    {
       "Serial__c" : "testserial"
    }   
    }]
}
```

This is the endpoint: `/services/data/v46.0/composite/tree/Order/`

Comment: Did you check this already? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100740/salesforce-rest-api-composite-tree-fails-cannot-reference-a-foreign-key-field

Comment: I checked but the scenario is different. I am trying to add a parent record related through an external id field on account and not to the same object as suggested by your link :)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this, if not just let me know